# How to authorize user role at a particular mvc3 controller/action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

How can I set authorization to a particular action within a controller?

Example (authorizes valid username logged in):

```
    [Authorize]  
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So, I'm looking to validate access based on the users roles...something like this:

```
    [Authorize]
    [AuthorizeRole="Admin"]     // This is psuedo but something like this   
    [AuthorizeRole="SuperUser"] // This is psuedo but something like this 
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Is something like the above possible?  If not what is the best way to secure access based on roles for particular controller/action security?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperUser")]
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460317.aspx

Comment: Ok, so I have added an admin role in "aspnet_Roles" and a user role (for my username/id) in "aspnet_UsersInRoles" but still can't get it working with "Admin, admin".  I also just added a connection string as follows: "    <add name="RoleProvider" connectionString="data source=localhost,1441;Initial Catalog=MembershipProvider;user id=sa;password=test" />

Answer (score 3):

```
[Authorize(Users="Jacquo, Steve", Roles="Admin, SuperUser")]
```

Users : Comma-separated list of usernames that are allowed to access the action method.

Roles : Comma-separated list of role names. To Access the action method, users must be in at least one of these roles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx